# Angular 5 css not found in nested component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have created one nested component (named - demotask) in admin-dashboard component. I have also created the required .ts and .html files for this. The nested component is appearing at the correct position but the css is not working for this nested component. All the styles/css are attached to the project through angular-cli.json file. I have used the following codes in the demotask.component.ts file, however, nothing happen.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demotask',
  templateUrl: './demotask.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

It is now looking like the below screen shot:

[image]

It should look like the below:

[image]

Comment: check if that file is loaded into dom

Comment: @Sravan Okay, how can I check the same? can you explain me the process?

Comment: inspect and check if they are getting displayed

Comment: @Sravan Oh! Okay! I inspected and saw the HTML in the nested component are in the DOM. Meanwhile, I updated my question and added two screenshots there.

Comment: css is not there wen you insopected?

Comment: @Sravan no, the css is not reflected there.

Comment: you can add thoise styles in `app.scss` and it will work in all components

Comment: I have already added the css's in the "angular-cli.json". If I add them again into the app.scss, will it loaded again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169430/discussion-between-sravan-and-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple styles in a component using `styleURL` property.

Since `app component` is the `main component`, you can add multiple styles there.

**Here is how it may look:**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    styleUrls: ["styles1.css", "styles2.css"],
    template: `
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <Label [text]="message" class="title" (tap)="message = 'OHAI'"></Label>
</StackLayout>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    public message: string = "Hello, Angular!";
}
```